# How deeply does IsAssignableFrom go when checking?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, casting

Lets say there are two assemblies with identical namespaces. Each of them contain a class with the same name but there are different methods in each assembly.

If I load both of them in a another assembly, and create an instance of this class (one from each assembly), will `IsAssignableFrom` return true between instances of the two classes?

I'm just curious on what will be the result.

Also, will it be possible to assign an instance of A to B?

In this scenario none of the assemblies has been referenced before compilation nor has a strong name.

Comment: Try this: `Console.WriteLine(typeof(Assem1type).Equals(typeof(Assem2type) ? "yes" : "no");`

Comment: Coming to SO to ask a question that you admit you are "too lazy" to investigate yourself is not the right sort of question to ask on SO.

Comment: I guess this will be equal as the assemblies have the same Fully Qualified Name

Comment: I could be cheating and say that it returns false, or something and ask for an explanation. I am not lazy when answering people's question here, though.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this should be possible to test yourself, so the "show us what you've done" part of the mentality of SO should come into play here. There should be no need to ask this *particular* question.

Now, you might end up with a question about *why* where it wouldn't be easily possible to deduce the rules out of simple experimentation, so here goes...

There's a couple of questions here, so let's take them one by one:

### Will `IsAssignableFrom` return true between instances of the two classes

No, it will not, unless one of the two classes inherit from the other and you ask the `IsAssignableFrom` in the right way.

That two classes are "in the same namespace" and has the same name does not make them assignment compatible.

### Will it be possible to assign an instance of A to B?

No, it will not, unless (again) one of them inherit from the other and you assign the right type of variable the right type of object.

Same as the other, they're not assignment compatible just because they're in the same namespace and has the same name.

### General Information

The *identity* of a class is also bound to the assembly it is in. Since `A` and `B` has to be in separate assemblies, they're not the same class.

`a.IsAssignableFrom(b)` will return `true` if any of the following are `true`:

- `b` inherits from `a` (does not have to be directly, can be several levels between)
- `a` is an interface and `b` is a type implementing that interface
- `a` is a nullable type, and `b` is the non-nullable version of that type

There is some additional information about generic types that I don't understand, but none of this applies to your case.

Comment: So the sort answer is that it goes as deep as possible when checking?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that. The two types are not the same, so `IsAssignableFrom` will return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Your type is only assignable to your other type if it actually is that type, or inherits that type.

The [`IsAssignableFrom` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) returns:

> "true if c and the current Type represent the same type, or if the
>   current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of c, or if the current
>   Type is an interface that c implements, or if c is a generic type
>   parameter and the current Type represents one of the constraints of c,
>   or if c represents a value type and the current Type represents
>   Nullable<c> (Nullable(Of c) in Visual Basic)."

In your case only the first two conditions would apply.

One type having the same name and namespace as another type doesn't make them the same type, or create any kind of relation at all between the types.

(Also, an instance of a class can not be assigned to another instance of a class. For reference types you assign an instance to a reference variable, not to an instance. When you assign an instance to a variable, it's the type of the variable that determines if it's possible to do the assignment, not the type of the instance that the variable is currently referencing.)